# R twitteR and Python tweepy different output from search

Tags: python, r, twitter, tweepy

I have been using R's twitteR package for close to a year now while I am relatively new to Python and tweepy. I run tweepy on Windows 10 and Python 3.5 if that matters.

The problem I face that the output I get from searches to Twitter api using two techniques provide vastly differing output. Namely, tweepy outputs only a fraction that R does. That, and with tweepy I constantly run to rate limit where as I rarely hit that with R (with Python just after couple searches I can hit the rate limit, which shouldn't be the case)

So I I do not know what I am doing wrong on Python side of things. Or whether this is a common issue.

For example using R with the following code provided me with 1565 tweets:

```
library(twitter)
consumer_key = 'stuff'
consumer_secret = 'stuff'
access_token = 'stuff'
access_secret = 'stuff'
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key,
                    consumer_secret,
                    access_token,
                    access_secret)

searchterm <- "#arsenalfc"

tweets <- searchTwitter(searchterm,n=5000))
```

On the Python side I should have exactly the same functionality in the following piece of code:

```
import tweepy


consumer_key = 'stuff'
consumer_secret = 'stuff'
access_token = 'stuff'
access_secret = 'stuff'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

results = []
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q='#arsenalfc').items(5000):
    results.append(tweet)
```

But the result? Measly 108 tweets.

I need to use Python so I would like the output to be similar to that the R method provides. Or atleast not so clearly inferior.

Any idea what is happening here? I am at loss.